# Unable to draw a line on imageview using Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

I am unable to draw a line on imagview. Below is my code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    private Paint mPaint;
    private ImageView img;
    private Bitmap newBitmap;


      float downx = 0;
      float downy = 0;
      float upx = 0;
      float upy = 0;
    private Canvas newCanvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        img.setOnTouchListener(this);


        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        Config config = bitmap.getConfig();
        if(config == null){
         config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }

        newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), config);

        newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

        newCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,mPaint);

        img.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          downx = event.getX();
          downy = event.getY();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
     //    newCanvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, mPaint);
          img.invalidate();
          downx = upx;
          downy = upy;
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          upx = event.getX();
          upy = event.getY();
          newCanvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, mPaint);
          img.invalidate();
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }

}
```

Kindly help me with this issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: the touch coordinates & the bitmap coordinates are not necessarily the same. Try touching on the very top corner of the screen and seeing if it has any effect on the bitmap when you lift your finger.

Comment: try commenting out the case for ACTION_MOVE, you are resetting the start coordinates so your start and end coordinates might be same. Put a log before drawLine and printout all the coordinates. It will also be better if you use a custom view by extending the View class instead of an ImageView.